# How I do "Loop create function in object and when call them after"

Tags: javascript

I have a **loop** that adds a function to an object for each iteration.  These functions are called later to change the *innerHTML* of several elements.  The problem I am running into is that the values returned by the function calls are not what I expect.  The results that I expect are shown as comments next to each function call below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var set = [1, 2, 3];
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
  obj['obj' + i] = {
    func: function() {
      return ['test', i].join('');
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("obj0").innerHTML = obj.obj0.func(); // test1
document.getElementById("obj1").innerHTML = obj.obj1.func(); // test2
document.getElementById("obj2").innerHTML = obj.obj2.func(); // test3
```

```html
<div id='obj0'></div>
<div id='obj1'></div>
<div id='obj2'></div>
```

Comment: You definitively should improve your English first ...

Comment: @AxelAmthor OP wrote enough for us to understand what OP wants

Comment: [Javascript infamous Loop issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue), [How do JavaScript closures work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```js
var set = [1, 2, 3];
var obj = {};

function func(i) {
  return ['test', i].join('');
}

for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
  obj['obj' + i] = {
    func: func.bind(null, set[i])
  }
}

document.getElementById("obj0").innerHTML = obj.obj0.func(); // test1
document.getElementById("obj1").innerHTML = obj.obj1.func(); // test2
document.getElementById("obj2").innerHTML = obj.obj2.func(); // test3
```

```html
<div id='obj0'></div>
<div id='obj1'></div>
<div id='obj2'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem that can be solved with [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).  The value of `i` is the final value of `i` at the time of the function calls not at the time of the function creation.  Using closure will help ensure that you are using the value of `i` at creation time instead of call time.

```js
var set = [1, 2, 3];
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
    obj['obj' + i] = {
        func: (function (i) {
            return function() {
                return ['test', i + 1].join('');
            };
        })(i)
    }
}

document.getElementById("obj0").innerHTML = obj.obj0.func(); // test1
document.getElementById("obj1").innerHTML = obj.obj1.func(); // test2
document.getElementById("obj2").innerHTML = obj.obj2.func(); // test3
```

```html
<div id='obj0'></div>
<div id='obj1'></div>
<div id='obj2'></div>
```